# How to solve Algebraic Loops error in simulink for 6DOF equations of motions

Tags: math, simulink

Block diagram '`FileName`' contains 1 algebraic loop(s). To see more details about the loops use the command `Simulink.BlockDiagram.getAlgebraicLoops('FileName')`  or the command line Simulink debugger by typing `sldebug('File')`  in the MATLAB command window. To eliminate this message, set Algebraic loop to "`none`". And I don't want to use unit delay or memory block to solve this issue. I need mathematical derivations so that I can make simulink blocks without any algebraic loop errors and I also don't want to use syms to solve the `n` equations and `n` unknowns. I don't want to change the dynamics of my system by placing unit delay or memory block.

where `U_dot=F/m-(somevalues)*R_dot+Q_dot,V_dot=F/m-(somevalues)*P_dot+R_dot,W_dot=F/m-(somevalues)*Q_dot+V_dot`
where `P_dot=M/I-(somevalues)*U_dot+V_dot,Q_dot=M/I-(somevalues)*V_dot+W_dot,R_dot=M/I-(somevalues)*W_dot+U_dot`

Answer (score 0):

> To eliminate this message, set Algebraic loop to "none"

The answer is already in your question. Set the error to "none" and Simulink will try to solve the algebraic loop. It will only report an error when unable to solve your loop.

According to the message you currently have the setting set to error [which implies that Simulink won't even try to solve.](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/algebraic-loop.html)

Comment: I don't want to set algebraic loop error to 'none'.

Comment: Any reason for this?